# SWRevealViewController misplaced constraints on swipe

Tags: ios, swift, constraints, swrevealviewcontroller

I've added `SWRevealViewController` into the app and almost everything's fine!
There is only one issue.
If `revealViewController` is shown on "`Swipe left`" then constraints misplaced.
If `revealViewController` is shown on "`TouchUpInside`" event then everything's perfect!

[image]

The declarations for events handlers:

```
if self.revealViewController() != nil {

        menuButton.addTarget(self.revealViewController(), action: #selector(SWRevealViewController.rightRevealToggle(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
    }
```

So how can I fix it?

Comment: Did you solve this? I'm struggling with the same issue @Dmitry